Is there a way to access a port by using any address within a /48 ipv6 subnet that bound to an interface instead of using the exact address?
I have a VPS that has a /48 ipv6 routed subnet and running a service listen on ::. However, if I connect to this service using any ipv6 address within that /48 subnet will not work. Only the exact /48 address that is bound to the eth0 will work. Is there a way to access this service by using any address within that /48 subnet instead of the exact address bind to the interface?
